# how do I manage css pseudo-selectors in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to apply a style to a hyperlink on hover.

I'm trying this:

```
#myID a
   text-decoration: none
   color: #fff
   &:hover
     color: #0077a9
```

However, the last rule isn't being applied.

Comment: Works fine with the online compiler (once the inconsistent spacing was fixed) http://sass-lang.com/try.html

Comment: Interesting. I've never been able to get it to work with a sass compiler locally. No errors, but no results.

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like? Which other styles are applied to the link? (Use your browsers debugger to look).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine, here's a working demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/6129692/

There might be an issue with indentation though. Your example has three spaces of first-level indentation, while two spaces are correct.

If this does not solve your issue, please provide more information: error text, resulting CSS file, maybe an example shared via http://sassbin.com